Token icon dimensions
What are the recommended dimensions for a Solana token icon?
I have deployed two tokens, one of them appear with its icon and the other without,
don't know what is the difference, thinking it maybe the dimensions of the icon.

Ripped directly from the Solana docs.

The image should be square, and either 512x512 or 1024x1024 pixels, and less than 100kb if possible.

There aren't any strict guidelines for this though.
Docs ref: https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/how-to-create-a-token#create-and-upload-image-and-offchain-metadata

The standard requirements are:
Dimensions: 512x512.
Format: PNG.
File Size: Ideally, keep the file size under 100 KB to ensure quick loading times.
These specifications ensure that your token icon is displayed consistently and clearly in wallets, explorers, and other interfaces that support Solana tokens.
If one of your tokens appears without an icon, it could be due to several reasons:
Icon Dimensions: If the icon's dimensions don't match the recommended 256x256 pixels, some platforms might not display it properly.
File Format: Make sure the icon is in PNG format, as other formats might not be supported.
Token List Update: Ensure that the token with the missing icon has been added to a recognized token list (such as Solana's Token List https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list ) and that the icon has been correctly associated with your token's address.
File Size: If the file size is too large, some wallets may fail to load it.
You might want to double-check these aspects for the token that isn't displaying its icon.
